# How firefox fill password when add username by the user?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on, browser-addons

I want to get signal of it. Because I am creating face recognition add-on (like master password) for firefox.

edit: when user add username I need to check user face. If only the given username and his saved face are equal, then only password should put in to password field. What I want is when user add his username execute my application to recognize face. I want to get signal of after adding username.

Comment: please elaborate your problem..

Comment: textContent & onfocus/blur would be my guess https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTextAreaElement

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Here on Stack Overflow, question in the form of "How to do X?" without any code shown or a particular problem described, is unlikely to get a good and complete answer. Also, you're still being not specific enough, there's a ton of approaches and things to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic naive solution is to [add an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) on all text `input` elements and listen for [any event that suits your needs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/), particularly interesting in your case should be `focus`, `blur`, or maybe [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input) events. There's also the [`element.onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange) property that might get handy.

Typical usage (simplified logic):

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = yourFunctionToCall;
}
```

Some additional notes:

1. It might be a good idea to add listeners only on pages that [have a stored password](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/passwords.html#search%28options%29).
2. It might be a good idea to add listeners only on pages that contain at least one `<input type="password" />` element.